# Melhores práticas para criação de Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Conheço duas formas para criar widgets, extendendo de `StatelessWidget`

```
class MeuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MeuWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('Meu Widget'),
    );
  }
}
```

Ou retornado um `Widget` 'puro'

```
Widget meuWidget(){
  return Text('Meu Widget');
}
```

Existe alguma desvantagem entre estas duas formas? 
Levando em consideração o primeiro cenário, pode ocorrer perda de performance devido múltiplos `Widgets` `build` aninhados? 
Em qual situação um é mais recomendados que o outro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O primeiro caso você está criando o seu próprio Widget estendendo e utilizando [composição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_objetos) de outros Widgets. Este Widget criado tem métodos e atributos que possibilitam ao Flutter manter um controle melhor da hierarquia de widgets. Ele pode perceber quando algum Widget mudou e precisa ser redesenhado, sem afetar e re-desenhar outros Widgets que não precisam.

O que você mostrou no segundo caso não é uma criação de um "Widget Puro". Você está criando um método que este por sua vez, retorna um widget. Quando você faz isso, e quer exibir esse Widget, você vai precisar chamar esse método dentro do `Build` de onde você quer exibir.(Num container, por exemplo).

Isso gera alguns pontos negativos:

- Essa função vai ser chamada sempre que o Widget superior for redesenhado, mesmo nas vezes que não for necessário e o Widget interno não tiver mudado.
- A sua árvore de Widgets não vai retratar exatamente a relação dentre os Widgets. Essa relação é útil para o gerenciamento de estado, para o gerenciamento da UI, para a depuração em geral. Sabe a variável `context` que o método build aceita como parâmetro? Ela não vai ter seu valor retratando a posição corretamente. Esses são alguns exemplos de problemas que esse segundo ponto negativo pode trazer.
- O código fica mais verboso e confuso. Você vai precisar chamar esse método em todo lugar que quiser utilizar este Widget. Se você precisa fazer um procedimento ou cálculo várias vezes dentro desse Widget, você não vai poder extrair uma função para tal.
- Você não vai poder utilizar as ferramentas que você já tem prontas por ser um Widget propriamente dito. Você perde o controle sobre o ciclo de vida dele. (Não vai poder ser notificado quando ele é iniciado, foi exibido/navegado, etc. Pelo menos não sem uma gambiarra bem grande.)

Então, respondendo:

> Existe alguma desvantagem entre estas duas formas?

Sim, como mostrado acima, a maneira correta e mais vantajosa é a primeira.

> Levando em consideração o primeiro cenário, pode ocorrer perda de performance devido múltiplos Widgets build aninhados?

Não, existe uma diferença do número de funções chamadas. A sua função `meuWidget` estará se colocando no cargo de uma `build`. Além disso, vale lembrar que o Flutter se encarrega de chamar o Build apenas quando for necessário.[(Aqui, no primeiro parágrafo, em inglês.)](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro).

> Em qual situação um é mais recomendados que o outros?

Recomendo nunca utilizar a segunda forma. Pelo menos não em algum aplicativo maior ou mais sério. Pensando de maneira mais abrangente, talvez possa utilizar para facilitar uma repetição, como por exemplo:

```
Widget criarColuna(){
    List<Container> filhos=[];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        filhos.add(Container());
    }
    return Column(children: filhos,);

}
```

Mas mesmo nesse caso, existem formas [mais elegantes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) de se fazer (depois do Dart 2.3):

```
children: <Widget>[for (int i=0; i<10; i++) Container(),],
```

Para uma leitura mais detalhada, [sugiro esta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951384/10746978) (em inglês)

Comment: Para complementar a resposta, existes esses dois links que podem ser úteis também (Ambos em inglês): [Splitting widgets to methods is a performance antipattern](https://iiro.dev/2018/12/11/splitting-widgets-to-methods-performance-antipattern/) | E | [What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234826/10145630)

Comment: Nossa que legal, eu desconhecia esse esquema de fazer um `FOR-LOOP` dentro do _array_ de Widgets