# Erro na palavra "context" flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Queria que a listtile abrir-se uma pagina especifica, mas está-me a dar um erro no "context".
O código é o seguinte:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: _buildListView(),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView() {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 20,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/image000.jpg'),
              radius: 28,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('INICIANTE'),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
     onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SignUpScreen()),
      );
    },
],
    );
  }
}
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro neste caso é autoexplicativo. A variável `context` não existe no método que você criou. A própria IDE deve estar acusando este erro.

Repare que o `context` é recebido por parâmetro no `build(BuildContext context)`, então você tem que passar também por parâmetro para o método `_buildListView(BuildContext context)`:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: _buildListView(context),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView(BuildContext context) {
    ...
     onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SignUpScreen()),
      );
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você criou essa função `_buildListView`. Essa é uma função que cria um widget e retorna uma instância dele. Como podemos ver [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449185/152025) resposta, essa não é a melhor prática neste caso pois tem algumas desvantagens.

Porém, no seu caso, o problema é que você ao fazer isso perde a referência a variável [context](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) que você precisa para repassar ao builder. Você pode resolver isso de várias maneiras, mas as mais diretas são:

- Coloque como argumento do método `_buildListView` um parâmetro context:

```
ListView _buildListView(BuildContext context) {
[...]
}
```

e passe como parâmetro na hora de chamá-la:

```
body: _buildListView(context)
```

- Outra forma é, como na resposta citada acima, criando seu próprio Widget reutilizável:

```
class MeuListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MeuListView ({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 20,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/image000.jpg'),
              radius: 28,
            ), 
          ),
          title: Text('INICIANTE'), //
          trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right), //
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SignUpScreen()),

            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

para depois chamá-lo em sua tela:

```
body: MeuListView(),
```

Obs: Você esqueceu um "fecha parênteses", isto é, o caracter `)` antes do colchete que fecha a lista de Widgets:

```
     },
   ),//Insira este
 ],
```

Não sei se isso foi só na hora de copiar o código, mas achei válido mencionar.